# Changing the color of a button changes the entire layout color to white

Tags: android

I am having a very weird issue in Android Studio. I've got a simple layout with an EditText object, and a button. When I go to assign the attribute android:background="some_color" to the button, the entire layout color becomes faded and looks white. When I delete the attribute, the background color goes back to normal. Screenshots and explanation:

Code before the background color is added to the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/clarksonGreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/EnterRoomNumberBackgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="437dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="526dp"
        android:alpha="0.1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/knight" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EnterRoomNumber"
            android:layout_width="246dp"
            android:background="@drawable/enter_room_number_box"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Room #"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_weight="0.09" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/GoButton"
            android:layout_width="271dp"

            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[Preview before the background color is added to the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/angve.png)

Code after the background color is added to the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/clarksonGreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/EnterRoomNumberBackgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="437dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="526dp"
        android:alpha="0.1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/knight" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EnterRoomNumber"
            android:layout_width="246dp"
            android:background="@drawable/enter_room_number_box"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Room #"
            android:textColorHint="#808080"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_weight="0.09" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/GoButton"
            android:layout_width="271dp"
            android:background="@color/clarksonGreen"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[Preview after background color is added to button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPo9w.png)

Any ideas how to fix this weird error?

Comment: use custom background

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you didn't assign the colour variable "clarksonGreen" in the Resource file Colors? If yes you should go to the Color variables and put in the name of the colour("clarksonGreen") and assign a colour(example:#e55656).

Comment: You should consider testing the code first! I am testing the questioner code and suprising what he is saying is correct! Your answer is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

First off, I cannot recreate the issue. Assuming that you have the color in your color file, I see nothing wrong.

You could try rebuilding the project, applying the color to the ImageView too, updating AndroidStudio or launching it on an Emulator to see if it does this there too.

If it doesn't work, please upload the whole code to GitHub so I can check it out more closely.